# Update QGIS Canvas while debugging

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, debugging, refresh

I am upgrading some QGIS 2 plugins to QGIS 3 and need to do some debugging.  It appears that the canvas does not update until the code stops running, regardless of any calls to `self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()`.

Is there a way to update the QGIS canvas while stepping through code in PyCharm?
I am using QGIS 3.6 and PyCharm 2019.1

Comment: Not sure how that might work, but I could see this being a really neat feature within a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Is it possible that the Qt event loop isn't doing what it normally does? Does the map canvas handle interactions like drag/zoom etc or is it completely non-responsive?

Comment: @Spacedman, it's non-responsive. Blue circle of death.

Comment: Then it seems that at the debug prompt the event loop isn't happening. I vaguely recall there's a Qt way of saying "go handle any pending events now".... Try the `processEvents` method on the `QApplication` object.. https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents

Comment: Yes, @Spacedman, that was the correct answer that would have saved me (and will save me in the future) many hours of frustrating debugging!  Thanks.

Comment: I'll post as an answer for you to accept... Am not sure exactly which object you need to apply the method to so please clarify when I've written it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your debugger is waiting for you to inspect objects or step to the next line, Qt can't process any pending events, so event-driven parts of the application will become unresponsive.

There's a method on the QApplication object that forces it to deal with everything on the event queue and then return: See: [http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) for documentation. So calling `app.processEvents()` should update the map canvas.

I'm not sure what the QApplication object (`app` above) will be in your debugging session - if you can add this in a comment or edit that will be great.

Comment: In my case, simply running `QApplication.processEvents()` was sufficient.  I can even run this from the Eval window in PyCharm so as not to leave the `processEvents()` lines strewn about the code, including the requisite `from PyQt5 import QApplication` in the Evaluation window if it is not otherwise required and already in the declarations.

Comment: Right - I wasn't sure if `QApplication` was a module with a constructor for creating `QApplication` objects or was, as it seems, an instance object instead. If that makes sense...